# As crazy as this drives me?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, phrases

Can we modify the phrase “This drives me crazy....” and make it “As crazy as this drives me...” in the same way that “This makes me mad...” can be modified to become “As mad as this makes me...”?

Used in a sentence: “So now we’re stuck in the middle of a forest. As crazy as this drives me, we got to start building a shelter.”

Comment: Sure we can. And if the rest of our prose communicates clearly, readers (or listeners) may even think it a bit witty.

Comment: [*After a while, **as mad as this makes me** sound, I started looking at photos of my family and husband and wondering if they really existed.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22As+mad+as+this+makes+me+sound+i+started+looking+at+photos+of%22) I couldn't find any similar constructions involving ***crazy***, but that doesn't mean much.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we modify the phrase “This drives me crazy....” and make it “As crazy as this drives me...”

It is not modifying – it is “changing”. And when you change something, the meaning changes.

“As crazy as this drives me...” => **Although** this drives me crazy...

Answer (score -1):

It's an interesting question.  I'm inclined to say, No, "as crazy as this drives me" is not grammatical, but that doesn't mean you mustn't say it.  It's a little language game that takes some effort to decipher.  If listeners figure out that it's a variation on the idiom "it drives me crazy", it works.  Otherwise, it won't be understood.  This is not as much a grammatical task as it is a literary one.

Comment: In the context of a complete sentence, what is ungrammatical about that clause, expressing, as it does the self-confessed craziness of the writer about something that is then explained later on in the sentence?

Comment: How is “As crazy as this drives me...” ungrammatical???

Comment: @HotLicks, It's a little odd.  A grammaticality judgement is complicated in a way that I tried to explain.  In general, idioms can be altered by transformations only to a limited extent.  My reaction to this example is similar to what I think about "The bucket was kicked by John Adams long ago."

Comment: @GregLee  - It's not idiomatic per se, but it's a valid twist on the idiom.  "As crazy as this drives me, I'm still going to see the movie."